# How to use mysql IN statement with wpdb update method?

Tags: plugin-development, wpdb

I am using wpdb update method and wish to update records where the id is not found within multiple ids.

So if I wanted to update records where each had an id of `1` I would do for example:

```
$wpdb->update( 
            'wp_my_tables', 
            array( 
                'active' => 0
            ), 
            array( 'id' => 1 ), 
            array( 
                '%d'
            ), 
            array( '%d' ) 
        );
```

But how would I edit that so it does NOT update values where the ids are for example `1,2,3` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately update helper only handles such simple equals conditions:

```
$wheres[] = "`$field` = {$form}";
```

For more complex queries you'll have to form SQL yourself and use `wpdb->query()` method to run it as arbitrary query.